numpy ignores "casting" argument
Numpy version is 1.26.4
>>> np.isnan('nan', casting='no')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
>>> np.isinf('+inf', casting='unsafe')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ufunc 'isinf' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

No matter which casting rule I specify it seems to be using 'safe', why?

'nan' is a string.  np.nan is a float.

@hpaulj Yes, it was just used it as a simple example to provoke this error message.

Casting can convert ints to floats, and work with different sizes. But it can't convert strings to numbers.  It's not the same as float('nan') or float('23').
